# corda transactionBuilder accept list of State as Input State

Tags: corda

I am trying to add List> as inputState in to TransactionBuilder by adding

```
TransactionBuilder(notary = notary).
                                    withItems(list of states,
                                    StateAndContract(output State, CONTRACT_ID),
                                    Command)
```

getting Wrong argument type: class java.util.ArrayList, how can i pass list of States as input to TransactionBuilder?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see [here](https://docs.corda.net/api-transactions.html#adding-items), `withItems` pattern matches states based on the class type.

```
/** A more convenient way to add items to this transaction that calls the add* methods for you based on type */
fun withItems(vararg items: Any): TransactionBuilder {
    for (t in items) {
        when (t) {
            is StateAndRef<*> -> addInputState(t)
            is SecureHash -> addAttachment(t)
            is TransactionState<*> -> addOutputState(t)
            is StateAndContract -> addOutputState(t.state, t.contract)
            is ContractState -> throw UnsupportedOperationException("Removed as of V1: please use a StateAndContract instead")
            is Command<*> -> addCommand(t)
            is CommandData -> throw IllegalArgumentException("You passed an instance of CommandData, but that lacks the pubkey. You need to wrap it in a Command object first.")
            is TimeWindow -> setTimeWindow(t)
            is PrivacySalt -> setPrivacySalt(t)
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Wrong argument type: ${t.javaClass}")
        }
    }
    return this
}
```

It is clear from this code snippet that withItems does not accept a list of states. Thus, if you wish to add input states, you would have to input them individually (i.e. `withItems(state1, state2, state3, ...)`). Be careful to add the correct state types (input states are of type StateAndRef and output states are of type TransactionState.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling `withItems(listOfStates)`, try `withItems(*listOfStates.toTypedArray())`.